# Raspberry Pi home automation

Tags: gpio, home-automation

Salutations,

I have recently gotten a Raspberry Pi, and am looking to use it as a home automation system using the GPIO and Python. Does anyone know any way to link light controls to the GPIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to simply rewire the light switches so that when you turn on the GPIO using Python, it closes the circuit. You can do that for a few light switches, but you might want to use several Raspberry Pis.

This might also be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84hV54FDK40&ab_channel=ShaneYake

Comment: Ill try to try that out thank you very much for help!

Comment: No problem! However, if I answered your question feel free to click the check mark underneath the arrows. :-)

Comment: @SirPiEater please do not connect mains wiring directly to your Pi. It will at the very least kill the Pi, and could do far worse. IF you are inexperienced with mains wiring, A better solution may be to leverage existing technology X10, remote controlled sockets etc. and control them from your Pi.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just noticed that they have low reputation, so they might not know about the answer check mark thingy.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I am not going to wire directly to Pi I was going to wire an AC switch that is turned on by GPIO signal.

Comment: @SirPiEater the switch is using household AC current (called mains). At a minimum you will need a solid state relay. Connecting GPIO to AC will instantly fry your PI.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Does this one work? http://leeselectronic.com/product/3306.html

Comment: @SirPiEater No it takes AC for an input the Pi runs on DC. Also shopping advice is explicitly off topic. Might I suggest you follow my previous suggestion google x10 and Raspberry Pi, or home automation and Pi, Also, I mentioned a solid state relay above (it could be done with a regular relay as well. At the risk of offending you, this project may be a little to ambitious at the moment. Might I suggest more research, There are several books that cover this topic, or that devote a chapter to it.

Comment: Ok will look over it some more thank you for the honesty I will come back after research. Sorry for off topic.

Comment: @SirPiEater this may help http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=raspberry+pi+home+automation I am not trying to be Debbie Downer just don't want to see you burn down your house. You can also search home automation on this site, or youtube as shojan pointed out.